# select multiple elements in array and convert them to list c#

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I have an `array` for example :

```
public static string[] elmentnames = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E","F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R","S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"};
```

and I want to select items from index 0 to 15 and put then in a `list` of string

How?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Presuming the elements are already in the order you want them, you can do it like:

```
List<string> elementNamesList = elmentnames.Take(15).ToList();
```

`.Take(15)` is the first 15 elements. From index 0 to 15 is actually 16 elements, so you can change that to `.Take(16)` if that's what you meant.

Answer (score 3):

Any of these will work:

```
var list = elmentnames.Take(16).ToList();
var list = elmentnames.Where((x, i) => i <= 15).ToList();

var array = new string[16];
Array.Copy(elmentnames, array, 16);
var list = new List<string>(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try creating a for loop that goes threw every element of your current array and ads them to an ArrayList I am not familiar with C# but the concept its the same in every programming language.